# Making multiple requests with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So my goal is to use WebClient to make multiple concurrent requests, wait until they're all completed, then combine the results. Here is what I have so far:

```
...

Flux<ServerResponse> feedResponses = request
        .bodyToMono(AddFeedRequestDto.class)
        .map(AddFeedRequestDto::getFeeds) // Returns a list of RSS feed URLs
        .map(this::getServerResponsesFromUrls) // Returns a list of Mono<Feed>
        .map(Flux::merge) // Wait til all requests are completed
        // Not sure where to go from here

...

/** Related methods: **/

private List<Mono<Feed>> getServerResponsesFromUrls(List<String> feedUrls) {
    List<Mono<Feed>> feedResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    feedUrls.forEach(feedUrl -> feedResponses.add(getFeedResponse(feedUrl)));
    return feedResponses;
}

public Mono<Feed> getFeedResponse(final String url) {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class) // Ideally, we should be able to use bodyToMono(FeedDto.class)
            .map(this::convertResponseToFeedDto)
            .map(feedMapper::convertFeedDtoToFeed);
}

/** Feed.java **/
@Getter
@Setter
public class Feed {
    List<Item> items;
}
```

Basically my goal is to combine all the items from each of the feeds to create one unified feed. However, I am not quite sure what to do after the call to Flux::merge. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.flatMap` instead of `.map` / `Flux.merge`, like this:

```java
Mono<Feed> unifiedFeedMono = request
        .bodyToMono(AddFeedRequestDto.class)  // Mono<AddFeedRequestDto>
        .map(AddFeedRequestDto::getFeeds)     // Mono<List<String>> feedUrls
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)      // Flux<String> feedUrls
        .flatMap(this::getFeedResponse)       // Flux<Feed>
        .map(Feed::getItems)                  // Flux<List<Item>>
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)          // Flux<Item>
        .collectList()                        // Mono<List<Item>>
        .map(Feed::new);                      // Mono<Feed>
```

Note that `.flatMap` is an asynchronous operation and will execute requests in parallel.  There is an overloaded version that takes a `concurrency` argument if you want to limit concurrency.

Ordering is not guaranteed with `.flatMap`, and the resulting items might be interleaved.  If you want more ordering guarantees, substitute `.concatMap` or `.flatMapSequential`.

Comment: Ordering was not a concern, so this solution did the trick. Thanks!